# Android App - Clicking on Button does not open new activity

Tags: java, android, button, android-activity

My problem is as follows: I have an activity `activity transport`. On this activity I have one button `Auto` which should open the new activity: `activity_auto`. Whenever I click on this button the first activity `activity transport` opens again. No errors are shown and the references are okay, I think.

I attached my code snippet

```
Class: activity_transport

package com.group6.travlhoe;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class activity_transport extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button btnAuto;
private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_transport);


    btnAuto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Auto);
    btnAuto.setOnClickListener(this);


    bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item){
            if (item.getItemId()==R.id.menu_start){
                startActivity(new Intent(activity_transport.this, MainActivity.class));
            } else if(item.getItemId()==R.id.menu_allgemein){
                startActivity(new Intent(activity_transport.this, activity_allgemein.class));
            } else if(item.getItemId()==R.id.menu_transport){
                startActivity(new Intent(activity_transport.this, activity_transport.class));
            } else if(item.getItemId()==R.id.menu_rechnung){
                startActivity(new Intent(activity_transport.this, activity_rechnung.class));
            } else if(item.getItemId()==R.id.menu_unterkunft){
                startActivity(new Intent(activity_transport.this, activity_unterkunft.class));
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.menu_transport);
}



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.Auto) {
        startActivity(new Intent(activity_transport.this, activity_auto.class));
    }
}



}
```

The XML-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/hintergrund">

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.3" >

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Auto"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:alpha="0.75"
            android:background="@mipmap/buttom_col"
            android:text="Auto"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Flugzeug"
            android:alpha="0.9"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@mipmap/buttom_col"
            android:text="Flugzeug"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Taxi"
            android:alpha="0.9"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@mipmap/buttom_col"
            android:text="Taxi"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Bahn"
            android:alpha="0.75"
            android:text="Bahn"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@mipmap/buttom_col" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.3" >

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:background="@drawable/shadow" />


        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:itemBackground="@color/colorWhite"
            design:menu="@menu/navigation" />

    </FrameLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Share the xml file please - activity_transport.xml

Comment: Check your if condition in OnClick method get the actual result.

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH How can I check this? Sorry but I am pretty new to programming?

Comment: log the v.getId() value return correct. Or remove the if condition then try.

Comment: have you added that activity in `manifest` file?

Comment: @skadoosh yes it is added:
<activity
            android:name=".activity_auto"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:label="@string/title_auto" />

Comment: Try another option to Onclick event. Add android:onclick="Auto" in xml file of  your button. Then call this method in your activity. Public void Auto(View v){}

Comment: @skadoosh If not added showing error in console but OP said no error it something onclick event method not fired.

Comment: onclick is it crashing. ?

Comment: @skadoosh sorry no the app is not crashing.

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH 
can you send me a sample how i can log the v.getId() ??

Comment: Somthing like this "Log.e("ID VALUE",v.getId.tostring());" log in android simply look https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#ERROR

Comment: Did you try without if condition?

Comment: yes i also tried it without the if condition - doesnt work

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH
I tried the logcat error message and this is the error I get when I click the button: E/Transport: android.widget.Button{a1aa735 VFED..C.. ...P.... 0,0-514,589 #7f0d0091 app:id/Auto}

Do you have any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Post the logcat image this single piece of line not make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Intent it=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),activity_auto.class);
startActivity(it)
```

You may also try

```
getBaseContext()
```

If none works use

```
activity_transport.this.startActivity
```

instead of

```
startActivity
```

Comment: hi none of your suggestions worked for me... do you have another idea?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a Listener.Try out the code below

```
btnAuto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.getId() == R.id.Auto) {
                startActivity(new Intent(activity_transport.this, activity_auto.class));
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: but I have already a Listener in my Code. See within my onCreate method

Comment: if loop not needed. You set already onclicklistener to btnAuto only.

Comment: I implemented your code within my oncreate method but the problem is the same